# Increase max heap size for node js build using nexe

Tags: node.js, nexe

I am trying to build my nodejs application built in node 10 into a binary and executing it inside a docker container. When I create a build for this I run the following command to make my build nexe app.js --enableNodeCli -f ['--max-old-space-size=4096']. Even though I pass this command the max size of the nodejs the heap size is not increasing from the default value. When I try to pass it as a cli argument while running my binary. I get an error of --max-old-heap-size is not a defined command line argument